# import a list into a dictionary value Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to import this list item from the main function:

```
character1 = Character("Conan the Barbarian")


for test_item in ["sword", "sausage", "plate armor", "sausage", "sausage"]:
    character1.give_item(test_item)
```

I am using class and in the class there is those methods to save the list to the character

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, character):

        self.__character = character
        self.__dct = {}

    def give_item(self, items):

        self.__dct[self.__character] = items


    def printout(self):

        for characters in self.__dct:
            print(f'Name:', characters)
            for items in self.__dct.keys():
                print(self.__dct[self.__character])
```

my output is printing only the last entry from the list, seems like the entries being overwritten. But I can't really figure why.

my output

```
Name: Conan the Barbarian
sausage
```

I want my output to be:

```
Name: Conan the Barbarian
   plate armor
   sausage
   sword
```

Comment: why are you using a `dict` to store a sequence of items, rather than e.g. a `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're reusing your key. Every time, you assign to `self.__dict[self.__character]`

Your loop `for items in self.__dict.keys())` is oddly written. `items` here is actually a list of keys, and will therefore only run once, when in actuality you want to run it # items times.

Instead, you could use a list (or set):

```py
def __init__(self, character):

    self.__character = character
    self.__dct = {}
    self.__dct[self.__character] = []

def printout(self):
    for characters in self.__dct:
        print(f'Name:', characters)
            for item in self.__dct[self.__character]:
                print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for it, got it solved, for some reason I thought the main loop was running through each element in the list and importing it as single strings not the whole list at once :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `self.__dct[self.__character] = items` line uses the `[self.__character]` as the key to append to your dict. In a Python Dictionnary, you can just add your list as easy as writing the key and putting the list as the value like so:

```
self.__dct = {
    "name" = character_name,
    "items" = list_of_items
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing this, I was trying to use the character name is the dct key and the list of items as the key value. but still thanks for sharing this :)